# Is there a way to keep the key navigation of mat-expansion panels inside mat-accordion when the expansion panels are in child components?

Tags: angular, accordion, mat-expansion-panel

I want to have a few expansion panels inside a mat accordion, so only one at a time can be opened and you can navigate between them using the arrow keys. This all works well if the accordion and expansion panels are in the same component, but I want to separate the expansion panels into child components to isolate the logic of the contents.

This is from the angular documentation and key navigation works just fine.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

But if I change it to this, key navigation doesn't work anymore. How can I fix this?

```
<mat-accordion>
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  <app-second-child-component></app-second-child-component>
</mat-accordion>
```

When the child component has:

```
 <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```